# adding brackets to a matlab string

Tags: matlab

I have this string in my project:

```
x = 'a124cd5f'
```

I’ve split it as below:

```
x1 = regexp(x, sprintf('\\w{1,%d}', 2), 'match')
```

The answer will be:

```
x1 = ‘a1’ ‘24’ ‘cd’ ‘5f’
```

Now I want to add brackets to the both side of x1 string. I’ve used this command:

```
x2 = strcat('{', x1, '}')
```

The answer is:

```
x2 = {‘a1’} {‘24’} {‘cd’} {‘5f’}
```

But I want the answer to be like this one:

```
x2 = {‘a1’ ‘24’ ‘cd’ ‘5f’}
```

How may I do it?

Comment: It is not clear what you want! `x1` is a cell array of char types, but what do you want `x2` to be? If it should just be a single char that looks like what you describe, you can use: `x2 = ['{''',strjoin(x1,''' '''),'''}']`

Answer (score 1):

[`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) returns a cell array with a cell for each matching substring. You need to explicitly concatenate these cells if you want them to be one string.

One option is to use [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
x = 'a124cd5f';
x1 = regexp(x, sprintf('\\w{1,%d}', 2), 'match');

s1 = strtrim(sprintf('''%s'' ', x1{:}));  % Use strtrim to strip the trailing whitespace
s2 = sprintf('{%s}', s1);
```

Which returns:

```
s2 =

{'a1' '24' 'cd' '5f'}
```

Comment: thanks but i need the commas too like {'a1' '24' 'cd' '5f'}

Comment: There are no commas (`,`) in that string. Assuming you mean quotation marks (`'`), I made a minor edit to the question right after posting.